# Push segue not working when triggered from Unwind segue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, push, segue

So I have view controller A, which presents view controller C modally, which (assuming that something is done on view controller C) unwinds back to A, passing some data, which immediately pushes view controller B onto its NavController via a push segue, passing the data from C. Everything seems to be working, except the final push segue doesn't happen. Here's the method to handle the Unwind segue in view controller A.

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    NSLog(@"Called");
    GameViewController *vc = (GameViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;
    self.gameToBeShown = vc.game;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNewGame" sender:self];
}
```

(The "showNewGame" segue is set up through the Storyboard as a push segue from A to B, ctrl+dragged from A's File's Owner to B.)

I can verify that the method is being called, from the Log, but the segue never happens. Is the unwind callback too early to manually trigger this segue?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's a timing issue I think. This is filthy but it works:

```
UIViewController *source = segue.sourceViewController;
[source dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
  // FIXME: Need to trigger this segue...
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"One -> Two" sender:@"blah"];
  });
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the answer for this at: [unwind segue / performSegueWithIdentifier: problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250481/unwind-segue-performseguewithidentifier-problems)

This only works if you move the logic from viewWillAppear: to viewDidAppear:
The downside to this approach is that you'll see a glitch on the screen during the transition.